# Azure Devops build variables not updating during build

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have the following variable:

Name: `TestVar`

Value: `xxx`

And the following script:

```
$testVar=$env:TestVar.ToLower()

if($testVar-eq 'xxx'){

$testVar= 'updated'

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TestVar;]$testVar"
```

The value after a run remains `xxx` instead of `updated`.

Comment: Where you check the new value? in the same script or in another task?

Comment: in the variable list. Does the variable only get updated for the duration of the task?

Comment: Only for the duration of the pipeline, after the pipeline over you can't see the variable in the variable list.

Comment: to update variable value "forever" you have to call the api

Comment: ah ok great thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of `"##vso[task.setvariable variable=TestVar;]$testVar"` is to update the variable value only for this build running, not for future builds.

If you want to update the build variable list you need to update the build definition with [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

An example of a PowerShell script that does it:

```
$head = @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" }
$url="$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/definitions/$(System.DefinitionId)?api-version=5.0"         
$build = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers $head -ContentType application/json
$build.variables.TestVar.value = "updated"
$json = $build  | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Headers $head -Body $json -ContentType application/json
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the change permanent you need to do it via the api as follows, otherwise its just for the duration of the run

```
$projecturi = "$env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI"
$project = "$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT"
$accessToken = $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
$buildID = "$env:BUILD_BUILDID"

$headers = @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken" }

$buildurl= $projecturi + $project + "/_apis/build/builds/" + $buildID + "?api-version=2.0"

Write-Host $buildurl

$getbuild = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $buildurl -headers $headers -Method Get |select definition

Write-Host $getbuild

$definitionid = $getbuild.definition.id

Write-Host $definitionid

$defurl = $projecturi + $project + "/_apis/build/definitions/" + $definitionid + "?api-version=2.0"

$definition = (Invoke-WebRequest $defurl -Headers $headers -Method GET -ContentType "application/json" -UseBasicParsing).Content | ConvertFrom-Json

$definition.variables.testvar.value = "Updated"

$json = @($definition) | ConvertTo-Json  -Depth 100


Try{
  $result = (Invoke-WebRequest $defurl -Method "Put" -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json" -Body $json -UseBasicParsing).Content | ConvertFrom-Json
}
Catch{
  $errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
  $errorDetail = $_
  $message = @"
$errorMessage
$errorDetail
"@

  Write-Error $message -ErrorAction Continue
  return 0
}
```